# ¿Cómo se hace un ls | grep "nombre" en powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell

Estoy haciendo un scrip en powershell,
quiero darle al usuario que ejecuta el scrip un listado filtrado de los ficheros que contiene cierta carpeta.
en bash seria por ejemplo:
ls | grep "*pwtruño.sh"

He intentado hacer dir | select-string -patterm *ño.ps1 , pero me busca la cadena dentro del archivo, yo quiero solo en el nombre.
También he intentado get-childItem pero es igual

Text-Path no me sirve poque quiero devolver el la lista de los archivos que coinciden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que en bash seria :
`ls | grep patron`
en power-shell seria:
`get-childitem -filter *patron*`
`ls -name | select-string patron`